# How can I get get a digit to flash, then be shifted to a new position with the same flash timings?

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code that I wrote is an example of what I'm asking in the title.

```
import java.util.Random;

// Models a line of 4 digits, each either 0, 1, 2, 3.
public class Digits {

    // Set up a line of 4 0s.
    private int[] line = new int[4];

    private Random random = new Random();

    // Shift all digits to the right. The right-most is lost, and the left-most
    // becomes a random integer of either 0, 1, 2 or 3.
    public void shift() {
        for (int i = line.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
          line[i + 1] = line[i];
      }
      line[0] = random.nextInt(4);
    }

    // Print the line of digits.
    public void printLine() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          System.out.print(line[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Calls shift() after 1-3 seconds
    public void randomShift() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep((random.nextInt(3) + 1) * 1000);
        shift();
    }
}
```

and

```
// Test class for Digits class.
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Digits d = new Digits();
        d.printLine();

        // Shift digits 10 times and print the line each time.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          d.randomShift();
          d.printLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to develop this program so that, whenever a 2 appears in the list (at the left-most end), the 2 flashes (say, on, then off after 0.2 seconds, then on after 0.2 seconds, and so on). When the 2 is shifted at a random point in time by randomShift(), I want that 2 to continue flashing, without any changes of timing in the flashing. I want this to happen to every 2 until it drops off the right hand side of the line.

I suspect the solution lies in multithreading but I'm not sure how to achieve it. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why the hell is the subject "Multithreading query?"???

Comment: Thanks isnot2bad for your input. The simple answer to your question is 'because that's what I decided it should be'!!! Any constructive follow-up comments on this would be welcome.

Comment: You're welcome. But you still didn't answer my question. I can't draw a connection between your question title and its text. If you want someone to answer your question, you should summarize it in the title. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question title and start of its text. My thinking was that the solution to the problem probably lay in multithreading so, instead of summarising the problem, I would summarise a likely solution and use a question mark to indicate that I wasn't sure of this.

Comment: OK. Then you're probably a victim of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log output printed to [standard streams or the console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html) cannot be styled concerning color, blinking, animations etc - at least not with the standard API of JRE. If you want have more sophisticated output, you should change to a graphical user interface, e.g. using [Java Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) or - probably more forward-looking - [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm). Both provide controls that are able to display styled text.

Possibly there are any third-party-libraries out there that support your needs.